# How to detect numbering in simple vba string replacement

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to replace numbering (Word's 1. , 2. , etc.). In a simple string and replace search but I can't seem to find the numbers.

This is for Word 365, and I'm using the VB editor in there.

```
Sub ayaya()
Documents.Open FileName:=ActiveDocument.Path + "\Doc1.docm"
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "SSS"
    .Replacement.Text = "PPP"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
With Selection
    If .Find.Forward = True Then
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
    Else
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    End If
    .Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With

End Sub
```

My word document looked like this:

```
SSS
SSS
1.  SSS
```

and turned to

```
PPP
PPP
1.  PPP
```

but when I replace the search to any variation of

```
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "1. SSS"
```

It does not find the text.

Comment: Your Find object is attached to the Selection object, but you haven't yet selected anything. Try setting your Selection object to the area of text that you want to search.

Comment: Isn't it selecting the inputted text in my first example?

Comment: Do you have the correct number of spaces between the 1. and the SSS ?

Comment: I think `1.  SSS ` in document can be a list in Word, so it contains Tab symbol, has own formatting and so on

Comment: I believe so, I can't even find the string "1.". I think that numbering (the bulleting) isn't something I input as plain text for the find method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not finding the number associated with the paragraph text because it most likely is a ListLevelNumber and these are automatically generated by the ListFormat style. In other words, they are not part of the physical text that can be found using a Search, at least the way you currently have it setup in your code.

A separate Search would be required to find the ListParagraph Style being used and then some additional code that would manipulate the ListLevelNumber if that is what you are attempting to do.

Below is example code that determines what the ListLevelNumber is on a given paragraph and then takes some action based on what the level actually is:

```
Sub IsSelectionListParagraph()
    Dim i As Integer
    If Selection.Range.ListParagraphs.Count > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To Selection.Range.ListParagraphs.Count
            Select Case Selection.Range.ListParagraphs(i).Range.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber
                Case Is = 1
                    Debug.Print Selection.Range.Text
                Case Is = 2
                    Debug.Print Selection.Range.Text
                Case Else
                    Debug.Print Selection.Range.Text
            End Select
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Numbering is a [ListParagraphs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Word.listparagraphs) Object and can't be searched as if it's plain text.

Comment: This "Answer" is of low quality as it doesn't contribute anything new - it just repeats a small part of what Rich wrote. While Stack Overflow does allow people to answer their own questions, there's no value in repeating part of a much better contribution.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23142570)

Comment: Thanks @Taplar, I'll do better.

Comment: And sorry @Cindy, I posted that before Rich and didn't intend to detract from his response.

Comment: @ecksdee Ah, I couldn't see that from the time stamps. Sorry!